# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen gestalten und bilden?

Tags: standard-german

Können Sie einige Beispiel geben? Liegt der Unterschied bei der Bedeutung oder der Benutzung?

Answer (score 0):

The difference of these 2 expressions is as well in their meaning as in their use: first you have to form (bilden -> build) something or someone  before you can arrange or transform it -> (aus)gestalten.

Both terms have the meaning of shaping and forming but **Bildung** is often used as synonym  of **education and schooling**, while **Gestalten** as noun e.g. is the titel of a subject for working (textiles Gestalten, bildnerisches Gestalten (drawing), technisches Gestalten. these are all new terms for the ancient subject „Werken“.)

Bilden is developed from an inner image (Bild),  gestalten is the active process of arranging or giving a shape to an existing, exterior objects group or things.

Look up also: Bildung / Gestaltung, Ausbildung / Ausgestaltung.

comparing the derivated nouns combined  with the prefix **Aus**- the difference becomes clearer:

Ausbildung:
training, instruction, education, training, drill, development, training,
 formation, growth, formation, development, design, construction

Ausgestaltung:
development, arrangement, organization, decoration